# ERROR: can't open file 'test.dvi' for reading

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below is an example from the TikZ manual, which I compile using LaTeX in the Texmaker software. When I run `dvisvgm test` in the command line it says it can't read the dvi file. How can I make the file readable?

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{animations} 
\begin{document} 
\tikz 
\node :fill opacity = { 0s="1", 2s="0", begin on=click } 
:rotate = { 0s="0", 2s="90", begin on=click } 
[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle] 
{Click me!}; 
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure that you compiled with latex and that a dvi was created?

Comment: I compiled with latex (not pdflatex), but am unsure if a dvi was created. I was able to view the dvi, but am not sure if that means if it was created.

Comment: just look at that folder on the commandline or  file manager,  is there a `xxx.dvi` next to `xxx.tex` ?

Comment: before running dvisvgm run `dir` or `ls` (depending  on your OS), it will tell what is in the folder. And check the prompt you see in the command line window. Does it point to the folder of your tex file?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I opened the command line from texmaker, and was able to locate the file using the 'dir' command. It didn't know up when I opened the command line from the opening screen though. Afterward I was able to run 'dvisvgm test' from the command line which was opened from texmaker.